# How to install MySQL 8.0 with lower_case_table_names=1 on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS successfully?

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, debconf

It seems to be a lot of trouble to get MySQL running with `lower_case_table_names=1` as can be seen in:

- [lower_case_table_names=1 on Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't let mysql to start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53103588/11942268)
- [lower_case_table_names Settings in MySQL 8.0.12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51803216/11942268)
- [Set up mysql 8 with lower_case_table_names on CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52937998/11942268)
- [Mysql : can't set lower_case_table_names variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50453108/11942268)
- [lower_case_table_names option not working](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90695)

I'm trying to install MySQL 8.0.19 on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. `lower_case_table_names=1` cannot be set after mysql has already been initialized, which happens automatically when installing from the package repositories.

According to the documentation [Server System Variables | sysvar_lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names):

> For APT installations on Debian and Ubuntu, however, the server is
> initialized for you, and there is no opportunity to configure the
> setting in an option file beforehand. You must therefore use the
> `debconf-set-selection` utility prior to installing MySQL using APT to
> enable `lower_case_table_names`. To do so, run this command before
> installing MySQL using APT:
>
> ```
> sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/lowercase-table-names select Enabled"
> ```

I did that on a freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 and ran `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` afterwards, but it did not change `lower_case_table_names` to 1.

If at all, what am I doing wrong? How can I successfully install MySQL 8.0 with `lower_case_table_names` set to 1?

Comment: Please check if these instructions work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103588/lower-case-table-names-1-on-ubuntu-18-04-doesnt-let-mysql-to-start?noredirect=1#53175727

Comment: @user2149308 They finally helped me to find a workaround at least. You have to respect the typo from the comments and add additional steps at the end to gain control over root again. I summarizd all necessary steps in an answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far, I can get it to work with a workaround: by re-initializing MySQL with the new value for `lower_case_table_names` after its installation. These are the requiered steps:

1. Install MySQL:

   ```bash
   sudo apt-get update    
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y
   ```
2. Stop the MySQL service:

   ```bash
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
3. Delete the MySQL data directory:

   ```bash
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
   ```
4. Recreate the MySQL data directory (yes, it is not sufficient to just delete its content):

   ```bash
   sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql    
   sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
   sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql
   ```
5. Add `lower_case_table_names = 1` to the `[mysqld]` section in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.
6. Re-initialize MySQL with `--lower_case_table_names=1`:

   ```bash
   sudo mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/my.cnf --initialize --lower_case_table_names=1 --user=mysql --console
   ```
7. Start the MySQL service:

   ```bash
   sudo service mysql start
   ```
8. Retrieve the new generated password for MySQL user `root`:

   ```bash
   sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql/error.log
   ```
9. Change the password of MySQL user `root` either by:

   ```bash
   sudo mysql -u root -p
   ```

   and executing:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPa$$w0rd';
   ```

   afterwards, OR by calling the "hardening" script anyway:

   ```bash
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```

After that, you can verify the `lower_case_table_names` setting by entering the MySQL shell:

```sql
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and executing:

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_%';
```

Expected output:

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |
| lower_case_table_names | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to create the directory `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` and the corresponding `mysqld.cnf` in there **before installing mysql-server**.

If you configure `lower_case_table_names = 1` in `mysqld.cnf` and then install the server, it will initialize with lower case.

Comment: Sounds like a good shortcut! Is it enough to insert this one line into `mysqld.cnf` and will other defaults be added by the installation or should you have a complete `mysqld.cnf` ready before installing?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, which is why I went with the complete config.